# JavaScript: array of integers, sum integer to each element

Tags: javascript

noob question... As the title, I would add for example 5 to each element of an array like this

```
array = [3,6,23,5,43]
```

Result would be `newarray = [8,11,28,10,48]`

Maybe with map operator?

Comment: yes, map is appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a map like this:

```
var result = array.map(x => x + 5)
```

Or in more traditional syntax:

```
var result = array.map(function(x) { 
    return x + 5
});
```